# How does one set up CodiMD as a personal wiki?

Tags: ubuntu, node.js, npm

[CodiMD](https://demo.codimd.org/) is great for collaborative work, but I would like to use it for personal notes on my laptop (Ubuntu 18.04), configured so that it works without an internet connection and uses as few resources as possible. The [manual installation](https://github.com/codimd/server/blob/master/docs/setup/manual-setup.md) seems like a good starting point, but the instructions assume knowledge of Node, npm, database admin, etc. which I am not familiar with. I don't need TLS, user authentication, or connections to cloud services.

This is what I have so far:

```
sudo apt install -y nodejs npm sqlite3
sudo npm install -g node-gyp
sudo npm install -g yarn
# broken: sudo apt install -y libssl-dev
git clone https://github.com/codimd/server.git
cd server
sudo bin/setup
sudo vi config.json .sequelizerc
# in vi, copy 4 "db" lines from "development" to "production"
# in vi, disable "hsts" and "csp"
# in vi, what should go in the "url" line?
# in vi, what else needs modificaiton?
sudo npm run build
sudo npm start --production  # fails:  sequelize db:migrate && node app.js
# what is the best way to start CodiMD at boot?
```

In short, I'm looking for detailed instructions for seting up a minimum 1-user CodiMD on Ubuntu.

Comment: For the URL you could use an alias via the /etc/hosts file as the.name.you.want to 127.0.0.1 for example, or use localhost (it's already an alis to 127.0.0.1). Also give the full output of the fail please.

Comment: Thanks. As it turns out, the "url" is for the database, so "`sqlite:///root/server/db.codimd.sqlite`" in my case. After other changes, CodiMD now runs, but there are still major config issues. I'll post here when I learn more.

Comment: I'd say you better not run it as root. You better have the sqlite file somewhere in your home for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured this out. I put it in an LXC container for isolation and security. I would welcome advice on better ways of doing these steps.

```
lxc launch ubuntu:18.04/amd64 codimd
lxc exec codimd -- apt update
lxc exec codimd -- apt install -y nodejs npm sqlite3
lxc exec codimd -- npm install -g node-gyp
lxc exec codimd -- npm install -g yarn
lxc exec codimd -- git clone https://github.com/codimd/server.git
lxc exec codimd -- bash -c 'cd server && bin/setup'
VMIP=$(lxc list codimd -c4 --format=csv |grep -o '^\S*'); echo $VMIP  # use this IP below
lxc exec codimd -- vi server/config.json
# in vi, under "production", set "domain" to the IP displayed above
# in vi, copy 4 "db" lines from "development" to "production", add final comma
# in vi, delete 8 "db" lines for "postgres"
# in vi, delete 15 "saml" lines
lxc exec codimd -- vi server/.sequelizerc
# in vi, set "url" to 'sqlite://./db.codimd.sqlite'
lxc exec codimd -- vi server/lib/config/default.js
# in vi, set port to 80
lxc exec codimd -- bash -c 'cd server && npm run build'
#test it: lxc exec codimd -- bash -c 'cd server && npm start --production'
lxc exec codimd -- bash -c '(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo @reboot /bin/bash -c \""cd /root/server && npm start --production"\") |sudo crontab'
lxc stop codimd && sleep 3 && lxc start codimd
firefox "http://$VMIP"
```

**Update 2020-04-26**: I have come a long way with CodiMD, but still love it. The steps below are my 'new-and-improved' install process. In particular, one should not edit `.js` files as I did above, use Postgres instead of SQLite, and http**s**.

Finally, if anyone is interested in a global search feature, I've added it to [my CodiMD fork on Github](https://github.com/bitinerant/codimd-server). However, it needs 2 important caveats: it breaks the CodiMD permissions model because it allows any logged-in user to find other users' pages; and I consider it 'alpha' quality (though I've been using it for 7 months without issue).

Here is my updated installation procedure.

- install LXD:

```
sudo apt install -y lxd
sudo lxd init --auto --storage-backend=dir
```

- create and update container:

```
lxc launch ubuntu:18.04 codimd
lxc exec codimd -- apt update && lxc exec codimd -- apt upgrade -y
```

- install CodiMD:

```
lxc exec codimd -- apt install -y git nodejs npm postgresql
lxc exec codimd -- npm install -g node-gyp
lxc exec codimd -- npm install -g yarn
lxc exec codimd -- git clone https://github.com/codimd/server.git
lxc exec codimd -- bash -c 'cd server && bin/setup'
```

- install PostgreSQL:

```
lxc exec codimd -- sudo -i -u postgres createuser --createdb codimd
lxc exec codimd -- sudo -i -u postgres createdb codimd
lxc exec codimd -- useradd codimd
lxc exec codimd -- mkdir /home/codimd
lxc exec codimd -- chown -R codimd:codimd /home/codimd
lxc exec codimd -- sudo -i -u codimd psql --command='\password codimd'  # set password to <pgpass>
lxc exec codimd -- sudo -i -u codimd psql --command='\conninfo'  # verify
```

- generate self-signed TLS certificate ([source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-18-04)):

```
lxc exec codimd -- openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 3650 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/codimdselfsigned.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/codimdselfsigned.crt  # use defaults except Common Name: $MYURL
lxc exec codimd -- openssl dhparam -dsaparam -out /etc/ssl/dhparam.pem 4096
```

- build:

```
lxc exec codimd -- bash -c 'cd server && npm run build'
```

- enable firewall (block outbound internet so we are sure it is not needed):

```
lxc exec codimd -- ufw enable
lxc exec codimd -- ufw default allow incoming # allow inbound https, ssh
lxc exec codimd -- ufw default deny outgoing
```

- run once to check for errors (ctrl-c to quit):

```
#test it: lxc exec codimd -- bash -c 'cd server && npm start --production'
```

- add user accounts:

```
lxc exec codimd -- bash -c "cd server && NODE_ENV=production bin/manage_users --pass $USERPASSW --add $EMAIL1"
lxc exec codimd -- bash -c "cd server && NODE_ENV=production bin/manage_users --pass $USERPASSW --add $EMAIL2"
lxc exec codimd -- bash -c "cd server && NODE_ENV=production bin/manage_users --pass $USERPASSW --add $EMAIL3"
```

- start at boot ([issue #46](https://github.com/codimd/server/issues/46)):

```
cd /tmp
printf "[Unit]\nDescription=CodiMD collaborative markdown notes\n" >codimd.service
printf "Documentation=https://github.com/codimd/server\nAfter=network.target\nAfter=postgresql.service\n\n" >>codimd.service
printf "[Service]\nType=exec\nRestartSec=2s\nUser=root\nGroup=root\nWorkingDirectory=/root/server\n" >>codimd.service
printf "ExecStart=/usr/bin/npm start --production\nRestart=always\nPrivateTmp=true\nPrivateDevices=true\n\n" >>codimd.service
printf "[Install]\nWantedBy=multi-user.target\n" >>codimd.service
lxc file push codimd.service codimd/lib/systemd/system/codimd.service
lxc exec codimd -- systemctl enable /lib/systemd/system/codimd.service
lxc exec codimd -- systemctl daemon-reload
lxc exec codimd -- systemctl enable codimd
```

- for debugging, view `log.console()` output via:

```
lxc exec codimd -- systemctl stop codimd
lxc exec codimd -- bash -c 'cd server && npm start --production'
#... monitor output; ctrl-c to quit
lxc stop codimd; sleep 5; lxc start codimd
```

- restart and connect:

```
lxc stop codimd; sleep 5; lxc start codimd
firefox "https://$MYURL"
```

- in Firefox, accept the self-signed certificate and sign in

Comment: How have you found CodiMD for your personal notes? I have it installed but it seems better suited to transient notes rather than keeping a sort of wiki or library of notes.

Comment: @Jeff - I still love it. It's the core of my to-do list and huge database of notes and how-to's. But I've added 'search'; see above.